# Does the existence of gradient in any function necessarily imply the existence of a subgradient at that point?

Tags: gradient, geometry, convex

First , I apologize if the question is not supposed to be here, or if it is off topic for the subjects dealt with in here.

I was reading on subgradients, with respect to convex functions in the background, [ $\delta f(x)=\{g: \forall y \in \mathbb{X}, f(y)-f(x)\geq <g,x-y> \}] $ and it is claimed that if there is a gradient , then there is a (unique) subgradient ( which is the gradient) . I understand that in the case of convex functions, but geometrically , the subgradient of a point should be a hyperplane that is a global underestimator of the function ( from definition)

So , if I have a function ( which is not convex) say $sin(x)$ , at $x=3\pi/2 $ , I understand that the gradient and the subgradient exist. But for say $x=\pi/2$ , the gradient exists , but the line is not the global underestimator. Does that mean that the subgradient does not exist, but the gradient does?

I tried googling, but subgradients is almost always associated with convexity , where the gradient $\implies$ subgradient holds true, so I am a bit confused. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: The sine is not a convex function everywhere: you are trying to apply irrelevant concepts.

Comment: Yes, its not a convex function , thats what I am asking. Is subgradient a concept specifically designed for convex functions? Thats what I am trying to understand. If its defined for functions in general , then can it not exist even when the gradient exists?

Comment: Your question is analogous to noting that people frequently take square roots of numbers provided they are positive and asking whether square roots are "specifically designed for" positive numbers.  In this case, a point where a function is not convex has no subgradient (that's practically a tautology).  As you correctly note, the claim about gradient ==> unique subgradient has been carefully limited to apply only to convex functions.

Comment: This actually clears my doubt . "In this case, a point where a function is not convex has no subgradient (that's practically a tautology) " Thanks! I know this was a stupid question, but I am kind of new to this and it was somewhat confusing